# How to find associated rows when I only know the primary key?

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all rows which contain the same value in one column, but I only know the primary key. I have read through the SQL tutorial at W3Schools, but I still can't figure it out.

```
ID    First    Last
111   Bob      Smith
222   Tom      Smith
333   Alex     Jones
444   Peter    Williams
```

For example if I only know the ID 111, how do I query with that and find everyone who shares the same last name? Meaning I would want the following two records returned:

```
ID    First    Last
111   Bob      Smith
222   Tom      Smith
```

Comment: W3Schools, and similar sites, are patently worthless.  There's nothing of value there.  It's just a collection of thin pages intended to be a sink for site hits (to show to advertisers).  The site itself has no depth and, ultimately, no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think of something like :

```
SELECT ID, First, Last FROM tbl_1 t1
JOIN tbl_1 t2 
  ON (t1.Last = t2.Last AND t1.ID = YOUR_ID);
```

Comment: I prefer this one over my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Last=(SELECT TOP 1 Last FROM MyTable WHERE ID=111)
```